How do I resolve this angular 18 build error?
I reinstalled my pc node, angular, using latest versions and my angular project will run locally but it will not build. This is a new issue it did not happen several months ago.
what: doing ng build gives me unpatched reference error on angular compile.
Node 20.17.0
Angular 18.2.3
I tried earlier builds of the code from July that worked at that time. The
same error occurs with them. I will try installing Angular 16 next and see if that works.
Again, the code runs locally without errors.
'X [ERROR] Angular compilation emit failed. [plugin angular-compiler]
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(patchedReferencedAliases)')
at loadIsReferencedAliasDeclarationPatch (file:///C:/Users/james/aProject/A30Insurance/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-WYWH4ABE.js:1507:49)
'
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

I am unsure how we can help with little to no information related to your environment. However, I will say to try and update Angular and Node to LTS, if possible delete any build cache and try again.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

When you say it runs locally you mean you can run ng serve (building with development configuration + serving the app) without errors ? And when building the issue appears means building for production with ng build?

I was able to build a vanilla program and use ng build successfully on the local box
After reading the ng build options I used verbose and got the following message at start of build:

C:\Users\james\aProject\A30Insurance>ng build --verbose


Building...
● [DEBUG] Failed to read directory "C:\Users\james\aProject\A30Insurance\angular:script\global:scripts": open C:\Users\james\aProject\A30Insurance\angular:script: The system cannot find the file specified.
polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js  33.7kb


Done in 32ms
scripts-Z5OFQL6W.js  85.1kb

ng serve works just find issue with ng build

install options - later ver js core still same error:

npm install --save core-js@^3
** need browser detect in app component
to limit colors by browser
npm install browser-detect.

-- npm install --save jquery
-- angular.json >  "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
note: history component has > declare var $ : any ; // for jquery

the program is huge about 30 components and about 8 services hard to debug piece by peace wondering of any more traces are available upon compiling so I can see which source mod is the issue or or the npm's an issue

this was working on prior versions of angular trying to research polyfills and angular 18 at this time. The polyfill, unfortuanately, did  not show up without --verbose why does compile not show this error at the first, that could assist none the less thanks for any suggestions

rephrase: no issues of same code  under prior angular  versions ... suspect poly with v18

Try to find all classes with "default export class" declaration, and change it to named export "export class". Also change all imports of this class from default to named.

thank you I will do this and get back tomorrow...

success:
using ng-build --aot false

solved this issue locally

can anyone explain ? thanks. we can close this.

Did you check  Your exports, because - "aot false" - it's not good decision...It also working for me, but it's not appropriate for me. I just move all components to last version with standalone - components instead modular - approach.

can you please explain the reason for the suggestion to change the exports ?

what is the reason exactly ? This will help me learn ! thanks.

We are seeing this with our Angular application as well, but only when isolatedModules is set to true and the sourceMap Angular build option is set to false(using the browser-esbuild builder). At this time it is preventing us from setting isolatedModules to true.
